# How to use Node-RED to switch ioBroker scenes

Tags: node-red

I try to switch a iobroker scene. I successfully receive a boolean from my alexa node-red node. I can see the output of msg.payload with the debug node. That switches from true to false and vice-versa if I use the alexa command. The connected scenes can be switch on/off manually in iobroker.

How do I control the scene with the true/false of the alexa node? What part am I missing? What does the scene need as input?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it without scenes and it worked right away.

[image]